# AngularJS — Promises have old information

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my first Angular project and I'm building a weather app that gets the weather data from a specific location that the user types in an input field.

A problem that I'm currently experiencing is that if you type in a location, then type in another, the deferred promise has the same location and weather info as the last (there are two async calls).

I made a Plunker of my project [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/6lHoOxnQFlK8IZhQgkFA?p=preview).  If you go there and open your console, type in two locations, you'll notice that the objects have the same info.

I know there are a lot of files on that Plunker; however, the only ones that are relevant are: `MainController.js`, `getWeatherData.js`, `setWeatherData.js`, and `getLocationData.js`.

Here's a snippet of the `getWeatherData` factory that gets the weather data from forecast.io and returns it as a promise (`getLocationData` is very similar):

```
(function(){
    angular.module("factories")
        .factory("getWeatherData", ["$http", "$q",  function($http, $q){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var factory = {
                getData : function(coordinates){
                    $http.jsonp
                    (
                        "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/e1ab2c9f6b96acf85206c6def727a48e/" + coordinates + "?callback=JSON_CALLBACK"
                    )
                    .then(
                        function(response){
                            deferred.resolve(response);
                        }
                    );
                },
                promise : function(){
                    return deferred.promise;
                }
            };
            return {
                factory : factory
            };
        }]);
})();
```

Comment: You're not using factories and promises as they should be used. Promises have state, and you are using this state for all requests. Read this article about [promises](http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html), and read again the docs about factories.

Comment: @OriDrori I will give it a read, thanks!

Comment: `$http` returns promises. Just return that instead of wrapping it in an extra promise there is no need for. `return $http.jsonp();`

Comment: @ste2425 Thanks for the help!  I fixed my problem by removing `$q` and returning an object; see my answer below for solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was how I was making my factories.  Also, as @ste2425 pointed out in his comment above, `$http` returns a promise.  With that being said, there is no reason for `$q` when working with http requests... it's just a redundancy.  I researched factories and found [this](https://github.com/jmcunningham/angularjs-styleguide#services-and-factory).

When making factories...

> Always return a host Object instead of the revealing Module pattern due to the way Object references are bound and updated

This is my new `getWeatherData` factory that works!  I also updated all of the other ones with this same pattern.

```
(function(){
angular.module("factories")
    .factory("getWeatherData", ["$http", function($http){
        var getWeatherData = {};
        getWeatherData.getData = function(coordinates){
            return $http.jsonp("https://api.forecast.io/forecast/e1ab2c9f6b96acf85206c6def727a48e/" + coordinates + "?callback=JSON_CALLBACK");
        };
        return getWeatherData;
    }]);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Factories should be used in this manner:

```
.factory("getWeatherData", ["$http", "$q",  function($http, $q){
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  return {
     getData : function(coordinates) {
        $http.jsonp(
            "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/e1ab2c9f6b96acf85206c6def727a48e/" + coordinates + "?callback=JSON_CALLBACK"
        ).then(function (response) {
                deferred.resolve(response);
        })
     return deferred.promise
     }
  }
}])
```